# KeyShot Python script batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, 3d, automation, rendering

I'd like to know if I can create a batch file that runs KeyShot in the background and renders like Maya.

With Maya I can create a batch file, call the python interpreter mayapy / my python script.py / the Maya file / destination folder.

Is it possible to do the same with KeyShot?

Comment: Why is your only tag batch-file?  I don't see any batch file code to help you troubleshoot so I don't know how anyone is going to help you.

Comment: @Squashman well i tagged batch-file, keyshot, script, python but the page says i need more points to be able to tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run batch file with Keyshot.

You can add a following line to your batch file and execute it.
\keyshot6.exe  -script  (optional script arguments..)

More can be found at,
https://keyshot.com/scripting/doc/6.0/quickstart.html

Vinay